# Finding differences using left join

Tags: mysql

I have two queries and i need to find out the differences between their result sets.My queries are as below.

```
select star_ident,transition_ident,fix_ident,min(sequence_num)
  from corept.std_star_leg c
  where airport_ident='KLAS' and data_supplier='J'
  group by star_ident,transition_ident;

select name,trans
  from skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars
  where apt='KLAS';
```

Those are my two queries.I used left join initially but failed to get the result.

```
select star_ident,transition_ident,fix_ident,min(sequence_num)
  from corept.std_star_leg c
  left join
  (
    select name,trans
    from skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars
    where apt='KLAS' and name != trans
  ) a
 on star_ident=a.name and fix_ident=a.trans
 where airport_ident='KLAS' and data_supplier='J' and a.name is null
 group by star_ident,transition_ident;
```

I tried above query but it is completely giving wrong result set.Can anyone help me to make this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and result you need?

Comment: And can you clarify exactly what you mean by "the differences"?

Comment: The rows that are absent in the second result set and present in the first result set need to be displayed and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to test without the actual tables, but one way to do it is something like this;

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
  select star_ident,transition_ident,fix_ident,min(sequence_num)
  from std_star_leg c
  where airport_ident='KLAS' and data_supplier='J'
  group by star_ident,transition_ident) t1
LEFT JOIN (select name,trans
  from deploy_stars
  where apt='KLAS') t2
ON t1.star_ident = t2.name AND t1.fix_ident = t2.trans
WHERE t2.trans IS NULL;
```

That is, wrap your selects into named subselects, and do a standard `LEFT JOIN` between them.
This will show rows that are in the first result set and not in the second one.

EDIT: To find rows that are in the second but not the first subselect, you can just change it to a `RIGHT JOIN`, select `t2.*` and null check on `t1.fix_ident` instead;

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
  select star_ident,transition_ident,fix_ident,min(sequence_num)
  from std_star_leg c
  where airport_ident='KLAS' and data_supplier='J'
  group by star_ident,transition_ident) t1
RIGHT JOIN (select name,trans
  from deploy_stars
  where apt='KLAS') t2
ON t1.star_ident = t2.name AND t1.fix_ident = t2.trans
WHERE t1.fix_ident IS NULL;
```

Comment: But sorry it is displaying some common rows also

Comment: @user2341693 Ah, I accidentally used transition_ident instead of fix_ident. Please try again.

Comment: can you please give me a query that finds the differences for the vice versa condition also?i.e getting the rows present in second but not in first

Comment: some rows are missing.. :(

Comment: Sorry..I overlooked..its working fine,..thank you so much.. :)